# a line depending on a parameter and a plane in a 4-dimensional space

Tags: geometry

If a line and a plane in a 4-dimensional space are not parallel, do they have a point in common? I have a problem with a case of these

Comment: Substitute $r = r_0+t(r_1 - r_0)$ into $r.n = r_{p}.n$ where $r_0$ and $r_1$ are known points on the line and $r_p$ is a known point on the plane with normal vector $n$. When can you solve for t?

Comment: If that plane was not a hyperplane, they may have no point in common, consider, e.g., the span of $ \{ (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0) \} $ and the span of $\{(0,0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The hyperplane spanned by all three vectors contain both the 1D line and the 2D plane... So how do you even define parallelism in higher dimensions? For orthogonality I assume having an inner product is sufficient. Is parallelism the existence of a space orthogonal to both the line and the plane?

Comment: Define the span of $\{a,b\}$ and span $\{ c\}$ parallel if the dimension of the span of $\{a,b,c\}$ is $2$.